# Yo not working on Windows machine.

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am working on a windows machine. 
Here are my node / npm versions

```
C:\dev\my-yo-project>node --version
v4.1.1

C:\dev\my-yo-project>npm --version
3.5.2
```

I am trying to install yeoman. Everything goes fine, but the yeoman doctor complains.

```
Yeoman Doctor
Running sanity checks on your system

√ Global configuration file is valid
√ NODE_PATH matches the npm root
× Node.js version

Your Node.js version is outdated.
```

And when I try to run any yo command it looks at some odd place and complains that it could not find the required js.

```
C:\dev\my-yo-project>yo webapp
module.js:338
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yo\lib\cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
    at startup (node.js:117:18)
    at node.js:951:3
```

It should not look at the place it is looking at. It should look at

```
C:\nodejs\4.1.1\node_modules\npm
```

which is set in the PATH variable.

Any help please.

Comment: It complains about you having an outdated Node.js version, have you tried upgrading? The latest stable release is 5.3 and the LTS version is at 4.2.4. https://nodejs.org/

Comment: I agree that there is a further updated version of Node. However, I can also see that it is looking at a location where the node is not installed at all. So, can someone tell me where yo looks for in Windows to find node location. It does not seem to be the PATH system variable.

Comment: Where npm is installed and where it would later install yeoman are entirely different so that probably isn't the problem. It can find node, else it wouldn't show you that message at all. It might however be using features not available in your version of node which could cause the crash.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ npm cache clean -f
$ npm install -g npm
$ npm install -g yo
```

Comment: Nope. Still looking at the wrong place. Still complaining about it.